# why a good choice of mod is "a prime not too close to an exact of 2"

Tags: hash-function

To generate a hash function, Map a key k into one of m slots by taking the remainder of k divided by m. That is, the hash function is

h(k) = k mod m.

I have read at several places that a good choice of m will be

1. A prime - I understand that we want to remove common factors, hence a prime number is chosen
2. not too close to an exact power of 2 - why is that?

Answer (score 2):

**From Introduction to algorithms :**

> When using the division method we avoid certain values of m. For
>   example m should not be power of 2. Since **if m=2^p then h(k) is p
>   lowest-order bits of k.** **Unless it is known that all low-order p-bit
>   patterns are equally likely**,
>   it is better to make a hash function
>   depend on all bits of the key.

As   you se from the below image if i chose 2^3 which mean p=3 and m=8. The hashed keys are only dependent to lowest 3(p) bits which is bad because when you hash you want to include as much data as possible for a good distribution.

[image]

Comment: You describe the case that m is exactly 2^p, not the case when m is close to 2^p, as asked.

Comment: But it is still (almost) true. Computing a mod 2^n-1 is same as grouping the number in chunks of n-bits and adding those groups.